# Losing persisted user in Handlebars Partial View

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, express-handlebars

NodeJS using Passport for user authentication and Handlebars as a Templating engine, I've inserted some Middleware that makes sure the `req.user` is available on all the app's views: `{{ user }}`

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  next();
});
```

This works in the main layout and every other view perfectly, but it seems {{ user }} is not available when I'm in a partial view.

In the main layout, I can check if the user exists and if they do, display certain menu items:

```
    {{#if user}}
        ...
    {{/if}}
```

In my index, where `{{ user }}` is still available, I call the partials like so:

```
{{#if posts}}
    {{#each posts as |post|}}
        {{> post post }}
    {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

***NOTE - I ADDED `posts as |post|` because I thought I can maybe pass the `post` and the `user` to the partial view, but it only allowed one argument***

In the partial view, the following code is never being rendered:

```
{{#if user}}
    <a href="#" class="vote-up" data-id="{{ id }}"><img src="../../assets/icons/good.png" alt="discUp" class="discup"></a>
{{/if}}
```

I've tried different ways of sending the user to the partial - I feel this is an acceptable (although maybe not ideal) way to handle it.  Not sure what I'm missing in the Handlebars documentation, though.  I thought {{#with}} was the ticket.

Comment: Which version of handlebars are you using?  Since v 2 this should be possible `{{> partialTemplate firstContent="something" secondContent="something else"}}`

Answer (score 0):

if you're using the npm library 'hbs', you need to include the line:

```
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials');
```

in order to register your partials.

if using express-handlebars then you may need to do the same thing as

```
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    extname: '.hbs',
    partialsDir = path.join(__dirname, "views/partials/")
}));
```